# element.style not working in typescript [Angular 5]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to set style of element with javascript, inside my typescript but it doesn't work. This is what I try to do:

```
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('current');
element.style.backgroundColor = "" + this.styles.style.mainIdentifyingColor;
```

but I get error:

> Property 'style' does not exist on HTMLCollectionOf.

I also tried with setAttribute but same thing..

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` does **not** return an array. It returns an `HTMLCollection` as the error indicates. But, the premise is correct,

Comment: This is not the idiomatic way of handling style changes in Angular. The framework provides *many* ways to change an element's style, and you should probably go through them instead of working around them. One simple reason being [change detection](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html). See https://angular.io/guide/component-styles | https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives

Comment: @msanford i know that, but in this specific case I have to do it like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to iterate over the array of `HTMLElements` included in the `HTMLCollection` and set the style property on each.

**OR**

If you prefer to only set the style on the very first (or only, as you may see it) element with the class name of `current`, then you can do this:

```
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('current');
element[0].style.backgroundColor = "" + this.styles.style.mainIdentifyingColor;
```

Answer (score 7):

I know am not exactly answering your question but did you try working with NgStyle ?
[docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

---

**HTML**

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': myCustomColor }"> 

</div>
```

**TS**

```
someFunctionToBeCalled() {
  this.myCustomColor=this.styles.style.mainIdentifyingColor;
}
```

Comment: This is admittedly the _best_ answer since it follows the _Angular way_. But I've been down voted so many times for _not answering the question that was asked_ in a similar fashion, I've stopped doing it. thanks for the answer.

Comment: I usually do this but in this case I can't since I use ngx-pagination library. I have to get the class 'current' after ngx-pagination initializes, so it is easier with js